# How to create button in a widget, which change its color onClick?

Tags: android

I was searching through `stackOverflow` and the internet, but I wasn't able to find proper information.

Of course I know what is `RemotViews`, basics of `onClick` method in normal activities, but in widget it is too complicated. I was searching for thing like: `PendingIntent`,`Intent` but didn't find anything.

PROBLEM/WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:

On my home screen widget, I have got a `button`. When I click, I want it's color to change, clicking on it again, I want it to be set to the initial color. On further clicks, I want this toggling to be happening.

Hope someone help me :)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity layout file, set button as

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

with default white color as background. Then in your java code.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable)view.getBackground();
    int buttonColor = colorDrawable.getColor();
    if (buttonColor == R.color.white) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
}
```

This will swap colors each time you the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using selector drawable color state list and set it as background for your button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```